# RepeatingElement broken for images?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I tried to create a form function to upload and process (in this case just display) several images:

```
CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"img" -> RepeatingElement["Image", 2]}, #img &],
   Permissions -> "Public"]
```

If I click on the resulting webpage I just see a bunch of gibberish. What am I doing wrong?

Best,
Max

Comment: Nothing that I can tell. I've reported the issue so the developers can take a look at it.